# Error Calling a Odata service in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, odata

I am trying to call a Odata service from the C# application. I have called the rest services before and consumed the responses in the C#, and trying Odata for the first time. Below is the Code I am using

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
            Uri uri = new Uri(BaseURL);
            client.BaseAddress = uri;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

            var response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
            var responsedata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I am using the same URL and the credentials in PostMan and it returns the response. But throws error i the code, is there something different we need to follow calling a Odata services.Please help with this

Comment: what odata lib do you use?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use a library to access OData. There are at least a couple of libraries that you can choose from, such as:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Client/ (OData v4)
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.OData/ (OData v1..3)

Comment: I have installed the Odata Client already. But still thowing the error. Do I make changes in the code?

Comment: Then your code should probably look like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437724/writing-a-simple-odata-client-how-to-query-service